# QIODevice::channelBytesWritten signal semantics

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

The documentation on `[signal]void QIODevice::channelBytesWritten(int channel, qint64 bytes)` says:

> This signal is emitted every time a payload of data has been written to the device. The bytes argument is set to the number of bytes that were written in this payload, while channel is the channel they were written to. Unlike bytesWritten(), it is emitted regardless of the current write channel.
> channelBytesWritten() can be emitted recursively - even for the same channel.

What does it mean that this signal can be emitted recursively?
How is this different from semantics which would be clear to me: signal is emitted only once for every chunk of bytes written (e.g. each time `write(2)` was successful the signal was emitted with the corresponding amount of bytes, as returned by the syscall)

Comment: If you look at [QIODevice::bytesWritten](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesWritten), it says *bytesWritten() is not emitted recursively; if you reenter the event loop or call waitForBytesWritten() inside a slot connected to the bytesWritten() signal, the signal will not be reemitted (although waitForBytesWritten() may still return true).*. So you can determine what recursive would be from there.

Comment: But these are just examples. Based on them I could guess that there are some things you can do in slot that would retrigger the signal that this slot was reacting to (and that will be the difference with what I described in the end of the post), but what are those things? And also why there are any?